# How can multiple entries be made in a data extension using the same email address?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions

I am using salesforce to capture and store data that has been entered/submitted into an online form. If a submission is made via the online form using an email address that has already been used the existing information is wiped and only the new information can be seen.

How can it be done so that every submission creates a new entry in the data extension when the same email address is used more than once?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the primary key is set up in the data extension. If you need new records created everytime a record is inputted then you may want to have the data extensions have no primary keys or use a field other than email address as the primary key.

More on data extensions here: 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_salesforce_data_extensions.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

More on creating data extensions and primary key set up here: 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_data_extension_classic.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods:

1. Remove any primary key reference, that way same email address can be present in the DE multiple times.
2. Use some other field as the primary key.
3. Use composite key, in the sense you can use combination of email address and some other fields as primary keys. One example is, you may use **email address + created date** as the primary key. That way, every time the creation date will be different and email address can be ingested into the DE multiple times.